# How to update data using session in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

This my code in codeigniter but it doesn't update in database, I'm beginner ni codeigniter, how could I fix this error, or what is wrong in my code?
THis is my Controller:

```
function edit() {
    $role = $this->session->userdata('role');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'firstname', 'required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'lastname', 'required|xss_clean');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        //set page data
        $data['title'] = 'Update Profile';
       if($role!=''){
       $data['admin'] = $this->M_user->get($this->session->userdata('user_id'));
      }else{
      $data['admin'] = $this->M_administrator->getAdmin($this->session->userdata('id_admin'));
      }
        $data['sitename'] = $this->M_website->getName();
        $data['content'] = 'admin/myaccount/edit';

        //parse template
        $this->parser->parse('admin/template', $data);
    } else {
       if($role!=''){
        if ($this->M_user->updateStatus($_POST['user_id'])) {
             //SAVE ADMIN ACTION LOG
            //save_admin_action(array('module' => Constant::AM_ACCOUNT, 'action' => Constant::AL_EDIT, 'title' => $this->form_validation['username'], 'object_id' => $id));

            //redirect page
            $this->session->set_flashdata('saved', TRUE);
            redirect('admin/myaccount');
        }
       }else{           
        if ($this->M_administrator->updateStatus($_POST['id_admin'])) {
             //SAVE ADMIN ACTION LOG
            //save_admin_action(array('module' => Constant::AM_ACCOUNT, 'action' => Constant::AL_EDIT, 'title' => $this->form_validation['username'], 'object_id' => $id));

            //redirect page
            $this->session->set_flashdata('saved', TRUE);
            redirect('admin/myaccount');
        }
      }
    }
}
```

This is my model administrator:

```
function updateStatus($post, $id){
    $data = array(
                'firstname' => $post['firstname'],
                'lastname' => $post['lastname']
        );
    $this->db->where('id_admin', $id);
    if($this->db->update('admin', $data)){
        return TRUE;
    }else{
        return FALSE;   
    }
}
```

user Model:

```
function updateStatus($post, $id){
    $data = array(
                'firstname' => $post['firstname'],
                'lastname' => $post['lastname']
        );
    $this->db->where('user_id', $id);
    if($this->db->update('user', $data)){
        return TRUE;
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that you are passing only one parameter in your function i.e $this->M_user->updateStatus($_POST['user_id'])
in model
function updateStatus($post, $id) and you are using the second parameter i.e $id in where which will be blank

Comment: So i only declare $post but the results is the same.

Comment: are you able to access the value of $post['firstname'] in model

Comment: yes i want to access firstname and lastname in model, i want to update firstname and lastname value,

Answer (score 1):

pass firstname and last name to your updatestatus model function if you are not getting that value in model so you are not able to change

print your query using $this->db->last_query(); to get query output and post your query here

Answer (score 0):

Change your where clause to
 $this->db->where('id_admin', $post);

Comment: When i replace $id to $post it store 2, and it never change,